# Is this possible: hasManyThrough through hasManyThrough?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Is it possible?

Consider this hypothetical relationship, for example:

A city has many schools. A school has many teachers. A teacher has many students. A student has many assignments.

With hasManyThrough, I can get all the students from a city

```
 public function students() {
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Student::class, Teacher::class);
 }
```

but would it be possible to get all the assignments from a city?

I tried these two with no luck:

```
 // City model
 public function assignments() {
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class, Student::class);
 }
```

(complains about there not being a foreign key for City on Students)

and:

```
 // City model
 public function assignments() {
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class, $this->students());
 }
```

(fatal error)

Alternatively, if this type of relationship is not possible in an Eloquent model, how would you go about retrieving all assignments from a city in the best way? My ultimate goal is to get a collection of assignments based on a city, so however that can be accomplished.

Comment: Something like this "sort of" works, but it includes all students and their assignments (if any exist). I'm looking for a collection of JUST the assignments: $city->students()->with('assignments')->get();

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work backwards to solve this problem:

```
return Assignment::whereHas('students', function($q){
    return $q->whereHas('teacher', function($q){
        return $q->whereHas('school', function($q){
            return $q->where('city', $this->id);
        });
    });
});
```